# Sql condition to return specific date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a date range using the following SQL condition in MySQL.

```
and a.timestamp >= '2016-03-29'
and a.timestamp <= '2016-03-30'
```

This returns 0 rows but when I try a longer range like

and a.timestamp >= '2016-03-20'
and a.timestamp <= '2016-03-31'

It returns the rows I want which is shown below in the timestamp column [image]

Please what condition for the 2016-03-29 and 2016-03-30 would return the row in the image. Thanks

Comment: The input date '2016-03-30' means that your time is at 00:00. So if you want anything up to 30 Mar 2016 23:59:59, try to put a condition like a.timestamp < '2016-03-31'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you have no values on 2016-03-29.  So, you only want to consider the *date* portion.  One method is to use `date()`:

```
date(a.timestamp) >= '2016-03-29' and date(a.timestamp) <= '2016-03-30'
```

However, that is a bad habit, because the use of the function precludes the use of an index (if available).  Instead, you probably intend:

```
a.timestamp >= '2016-03-29' and a.timestamp < '2016-03-31'
```

Note the change of `<=` to `<` for the second condition.  This gets everything before that date, but not at midnight when the day begins.

Answer (score 3):

Any time after midnight 2016-03-30 is greater than 2016-03-30, so you need to check like this to get values like "2016-03-30 15:55"

```
and a.timestamp >= '2016-03-29'
and a.timestamp < '2016-03-31'
```

This will return all datetime values on March 29th and March 30th.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `CONVERT` the date, stripping the time:

```
and CONVERT(a.timestamp, date) >= '2016-03-29'
and CONVERT(a.timestamp, date) <= '2016-03-31'
```

The reason your query is not returning certain rows is because `2016-03-31 00:00:01` is greater than `2016-03-31`

You can also make use of the `BETWEEN` clause:

`AND CONVERT(a.timestamp, date) BETWEEN '2016-03-29' AND '2016-03-31'`